# Print computer userName on an RTF rather than MS Office UserName

Tags: microsoft-word, rtf

First question ever on Stack.

I am creating an RTF in MS Word.  I want to print the computer username in the footer to identify which user printed the document out.  Everything I can find directs me to adding a 'field' and choosing UserName but that is the username of MS Office NOT the logged in user that is printing the RTF.

This RTF will be uploaded to a remote program which will populate the RTF with data and make it available to print locally so I need the RTF to pick up the local username instead of whatever the person put in when they installed Office.

It's easy enough to do this in code when the RTF/ Word document is generated locally but I'm not sure how to do it for various users dynamically.  Or if it can be done at all.

Thanks for input!

Comment: I don't think it is the same because this RTF is uploaded to a server.  Users print from links in that server.  There'd be no where to initiate that vbscript.  Unless you can include vbscript in an RTF that automatically initiates?

Comment: Word doesn't have a field code for this, so anything that's done must be done using code. Not sure what youi mean by "generated locally" vs. "various users dynamically"... Perhaps the best thing would be to put a "placeholder" in the footer then use a code tool to open the RTF file (as a file, not in Word - RTF is "plain text") and replace the place-holder with the user name in question?

Comment: What I mean by uploading the RTF is that this is created locally as an RTF in Word but is then uploaded to a program which lives on a remote server.  That program then populates the fields on RTF and opens a print dialog.  So I have nowhere to contain code that would grab the logged on user, unless there is a way to contain that within the RTF itself (which is what I'd love to find).  :)